# Loop empties model contents on every iteration

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I know I'm missing something fundamental here. I have a nested loop sequence to filter out songs from a set of albums that were added to a specific playlist. Here's my code:

```
foreach (var item in model.Albums)
{
    foreach (var song in model.PlaylistSongs)
    {
        model.Songs = item.Songs.Where(x => x.SongID == song.SongID).ToList();
        foreach (var single in model.Songs)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Loop");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(single.Album.AccountInfo.DisplayName);
        }
    }

}
```

Where:

```
model.Albums is List<Albums> // albums identified with a song used in the playlist
model.PlaylistSongs is List<PlaylistSongs> // list of all songs found in specific playlist
model.Songs is List<Songs> // resultant model
```

I have a debug loop in to show the contents of the `model.Songs` as it appends. It should show something like this:

```
Loop
Koda
Loop
Koda
Danrell
Loop
Koda
Danrell
Attom
```

However, all I see is this, thus the model is getting wiped on every iteration:

```
Loop
Koda
Loop
Danrell
Loop
Attom
```

Is there a way to append? I tried `model.Songs.Add(item.Songs.Wherex => x.SongID == song.SongID).ToList())` but it gave me an exception `Cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<Domain.Data.Song> to Doman.Data.Song.`

Comment: Have you tried Addrange? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi @MongZhu just tried it per Johns suggested answer. It gave me `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning to the `Songs` property instead of adding to it. So each loop it gets a fresh copy.

Instead of

```
model.Songs = item.Songs.Where(x => x.SongID == song.SongID).ToList();
```

Try

```
model.Songs.AddRange(item.Songs.Where(x => x.SongID == song.SongID));
```

That is the smallest change to get you working. Note that you will have to instantiate the list before you start the loop, e.g. `model.Songs = new List<Song>()`.

If the point though it to use LINQ to its full potential, you should get rid of the loop and let LINQ do it for you.

Instead of:

```
foreach (var item in model.Albums)
{
    foreach (var song in model.PlaylistSongs)
    {
        model.Songs = item.Songs.Where(x => x.SongID == song.SongID).ToList();
        foreach (var single in model.Songs)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Loop");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(single.Album.AccountInfo.DisplayName);
        }
    }
}
```

Try this:

```
model.Songs = model.Albums
    .SelectMany       //Combine all albums songs into one list
    (
        a => a.Songs 
    )
    .Where           //Only take those that are in the playlist
    (
        s => model.PlaylistSongs.Any
        ( 
            p => p.SongID == s.SongID 
        )
    )
    .ToList();

foreach (var single in model.Songs)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(single.Album.AccountInfo.DisplayName);
}
```

Comment: update, so I tried both methods, the first option with loops gives me a `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` on the `AddRange` line and the new LINQ method returns the same as I had in my original question. What more information do you need to help resolve? @John

Comment: You will need to create an empty list to put the items into before you start the loops, e.g. `model.Songs = new List<Song>();`

Comment: okay so that resolved the instance error, but now the same incorrect result is output (where it only displays one artist per loop). Tested again with LINQ method again too

Comment: ok I'm  dumb I was thinking about my debug loop wrong. You are correct thank you! Am confused as to why I had to instantiate an empty new list though since in my Model I have `public List<Song> Songs` set.